# Awk width of the columns

Tags: awk

I have a file:

```
To jest długi string z wieloma polskimi literami ąółżęś kodowany w UTF8, 
żeby 
było śmieszniej, haha.
ą
a
```

I have tried:

```
awk '{printf "%.80s %s\n", $0, length}' file
```

I received:

```
To jest długi string z wieloma polskimi literami ąółżęś kodowany w UTF8,  73
żeby  5
było śmieszniej, haha. 22
ą 1
a 1
```

I want to get the result:

```
To jest długi string z wieloma polskimi literami ąółżęś kodowany w UTF8,  73
żeby                                                                      5
było śmieszniej, haha.                                                    22
ą                                                                         1
a                                                                         1
```

[I want to get the result:](http://s22.postimg.org/qoctspji9/zrzut_ekranu.png)

Comment: The `-` flag left justifies the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The precision of the string conversion specifier gives the hard maximum space used. If you want to have a fixed minimum space used then give the field width of the specifier instead. And if you want it left-aligned then use the left alignment flag.

```
%-80s
```

Comment: @fedorqui: Good call, fixing.